# WinRT: how can I get type of processor (c#)

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I need to  determine if type of processor is ARM processor (for desktop application)?

Comment: If you want to test this in a Desktop app:  `bool is_arm() { return false; }`.  There are no third-party Desktop apps on Windows on ARM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call [`GetNativeSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724340.aspx) and test whether the returned `wProcessorArchitecture` is `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_ARM`.